# How to limit max rss memory size in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, memory, limit

We got a nodejs service running on a cloud server, giving it only 512MB RAM (more than enough for the application).

The server have slowly growing memory usage. And the server is automatically rebooted when reading 512MB memory limit.

I've tried reading memory usage stats with good amount of load testing, and the number shows a slowly growing `rss memory usage`, but very steady low `heap memory usage`.

I tried `--max_old_space_size` but that only limits the heap size, which is never a problem for me. The heap size reading is constantly under 50MB.

Is there a way to limit `rss memory size`?

---

1. Some quick research says the difference between `rss` and `heap` is buffer size from c++ code. Not sure if it's possible to debug those at all (gdb?).
2. Some say v8 has a limit of 1.4GB, is that also heap size limit? If it's rss limit, maybe I can modify nodejs source code, build a special version with smaller limit?
3. I've tried `--expose-gc` and cleanup gc frequently, but again, only help heap usage (and slow it down).

---

Update: found the reason, growing rss usage is due to a c++ memory leak from one of the libraries we used (thanks `bignum`). Avoid using it keeps rss memory steady.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/ package instead.